# How do you add a THEAD to an ASP (2.0) HTMLTable?

Tags: asp.net, html

to Add rows, I just do this:

```
Table1.Rows.Add(row)
```

How would I add a thead?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uh oh.. just foind it..

A complex table model is not supported. You cannot have an HtmlTable control with nested , , , , , or  elements. These elements are removed without warning and do not appear in the output HTML. An exception will be thrown if you attempt to programmatically add these table model elements to the Control.Controls collection of the HtmlTable control.

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It figures, doesn't it?